# fetch_assoc() error

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error that says Call to a member function fetch_array() on boolean on line 23.
Line 23 consists of this line of code

```
$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Here is the whole block

```
if(!filter_has_var(INPUT_GET, 'id')) {
echo "Error: book id was not found.";
require_once ('includes/footer.php');
exit();
}
$book_id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id=" . $book_id;

$query = $conn->query($sql);

$row = $query->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: echo `$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id=" . $book_id;
` and check your query

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
$query = $conn->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."[$sql]");
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

> **Always check for errors when running a query.**

Comment: after adding this the notice said that I had an error in my sql syntax, which I don't see one

Comment: Chnage your sql like `$sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE book_id= '$book_id' ";`

Comment: that got rid of the error but i still can't access the data from MySQL.        `echo $row['author']` should display the value in the author row from the database and its just showing blank

Comment: I think there is no data with that